# how to set StructuredRel using django-neomodel and modelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, neomodel

this is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Position, PositionRelForm

class PositionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Position
        fields = '__all__'

class PositionRelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PositionRel
        fields = '__all__'
```

and this is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django_neomodel import DjangoNode
from neomodel import StructuredNode, StringProperty, DateTimeProperty, UniqueIdProperty, Relationship, StructuredRel
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class PositionRel(StructuredRel):
    since = DateTimeProperty(default=lambda: datetime.now(pytz.utc))
    distance = StringProperty()
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'highways'

class Position(DjangoNode):
    kind = StringProperty(unique_index=True)
    created_at = DateTimeProperty(default=datetime.utcnow)
    road_to = Relationship('Position','ROAD_TO', model=PositionRel)
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'highways'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('position_list')
```

and when I run the server I got this error :

AttributeError: type object 'Position' has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: Please briefly describe “django-neomodel” in the question, with a link to the home page or documentation.

Comment: actually now im stuck at the exact same part

Comment: Here's a link to django-neomodel's documentation: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/django-neomodel